# Convert list of list into one big list python

Tags: python, list, enumeration

I have a list like:

```
list1 = [1  2  1 ... 1  399]
```

And another one:

```
list2 = [5 4  3  4  2 0]
```

list1 has numbers from `0 to 399`, with duplicates and its length is `5000`, `list2` has  length of `400`, the index of each `list2` elements represents the number of the element in `list1`, that's why it has `400` length.
I want to return a list that has a length of `5000` (same as list1), with checking each element, if the first element of list1 is 1, I want to add the index of 1 in list2 into the new list, which in this case is 4,
so the new list should be

```
new_list = [ 4 , ...]
```

and so on for all the items until it comes

I tried this but didn't work:

```
labels=labels.tolist()
labels2=labels2.tolist()
new=list()

for i in range(len(labels1)):
     for item,index in enumerate(labels2):

         # print(item)
          if labels1[i] == index :
             # print (str(labels2[i]).index)
              new.append(item)

print(new)
```

Comment: Please complete the desired result, ```new_list```, for the two inputs given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index into list2, based on the value in list1, for each value of list1. You can build this from a for-loop:

```
new_list = []
for k in list1:
  new_list.append(list2[k]) #lookup the value in list2 at the index given by list1
```

This is more Pythonically expressed with a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [list2[k] for k in list1]
```

Answer (score 2):

list comprehension.

```
n_l = [list2[i] for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

one of very fast and efficient solutions would be using of numpy module:

```
In [46]: a1[l2]
Out[46]: array([4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

setup:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1,2,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,7,8,9]
l2 = [5,4,3,2,0,1]
a1 = np.array(l1)
```

Comment: This is the other way around. He want's the value of l2 that correspond for each index given by l1, so it would be: `a2[l1]`

Answer (score -1):

Build a dictionary from the index of the list2 item to the item itedelf and then pass the list 1 item through the dictionary:

```
new_dict={}
for i,v in enumerate(list2):
    new_dict[i]=v

new_list=[]
for i in list1:
    new_list.append(new_dict[i])

print new_list
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be appending ```new_dict[i]```?